# In C#, how do i write the tostring function for all types of classes with a extension method

Tags: c#, oop, tostring

In C#, how do you override the tostring function for all types of classes and also for a class that contains a field that is a collection, such as a list, array, etc.

```
        public static string ToStringProperty<T>(this T t)
        {

            string str = "";
            foreach (PropertyInfo item in t.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                var enumerable = item.GetValue(t, null) as IEnumerable;
                if (enumerable != null && !(enumerable is string))
                {
                    foreach (PropertyInfo a in enumerable.GetType().GetProperties())
                    {
                        str += "\n" + a.Name +
          ": " + a.GetValue(enumerable,null);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    str += "\n" + item.Name +
               ": " + item.GetValue(t, null);
                }
            }
            return str;
        }
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? There's no reason to force types to use a custom `ToString()` implementation. If you want to save or export a set of objects to string you need a serializer

Comment: and what if it contains another class ? ... check if T is primitive or string then dump ... check if null and dump null ...
check if it's enumerable then iterate and call recursively for elements ... and finally  for each property/fields dump name and call recursively for value ... easy peasy (of course not as overriten but as fx ToStringEx extension)

Answer (score 4):

You can only override methods on classes you actually control, meaning there's no way to override this for built in types, types provided by  libraries, or types controlled by other teams in an organization (without their cooperation).

If you really only need this for a few classes, you will get MUCH better performance implementing it for each class, instead of trying for a generic method using reflection (this is why it's not provided by default).

If you want to do this for a LOT of classes and avoid repeating code, you do have a few options, but *NONE* of them can replace the built-in `ToString()`:

- You can make an extension method on the `Object` type
- You can make an interface your classes will implement (the most recent version of C# allows a default method implentation)
- You can make a common base class for the types you care about (this can fully replace `ToString()`, but only for types that inherit from it)
- You can make your own ToString() method on another type that accepts an Object argument an returns a string.

For any of these to work, the method would need to be *recursive*, because a property may itself be a complex type.

But **what you should really look at is serialization**. Specifically, the pseudocode in the question creations results that are similar to JSON. It's not quite the same, but there are similarities. So if you have some flexibility on your output format you can use one of the readily-available (and there are several) JSON serializes. This also gives you the benefit of compatibility with JSON parsers for later re-materialization of the data, if needed.